# Sort an array by grade

Tags: php, arrays

```
    $students = array (
     256 => array ('name' => 'Jon', 'grade' => 98.5),
     2 => array ('name' => 'Vance', 'grade' => 85.1),
     9 => array ('name' => 'Stephen', 'grade' => 94.0),
     364 => array ('name' => 'Steve', 'grade' => 85.1),
     68 => array ('name' => 'Rob', 'grade' => 74.6)
     );

 function grade_sort($x,$y){
  return ($x['grade'] < $y['grade']);
  }
uasort ($students, 'grade_sort');
```

i am a new learner of php,i can't understand the above code well. could i change this  `return ($x['grade'] < $y['grade']);` to  `return $x < $y;`  if not, why? thank you

Comment: you show `grade_sort` but your code calls `name_sort` are you trying to sort by name or grade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could i change this `return ($x['grade'] < $y['grade']);` to `return $x < $y;`?

No. `$x` and `$y` will be one of the arrays inside `$students`.
E.g. `$x` may be `array('name' => 'Jon', 'grade' => 98.5)`
and `$y` may be `array('name' => 'Vance', 'grade' => 85.1)`.
So `return $x < $y` doesn't make sense.

That code isn't very good though. The comparison function `grade_sort` takes two elements at a time and should return `0` if both elements are considered equal, a negative number if the first is lower and a positive number if the second lower. Yours returns `true` or `false`. The correct code would be:

```
function grade_sort($x, $y){
    return $y['grade'] - $x['grade'];
}
uasort($students, 'grade_sort');
```

`uasort` simply keeps calling this function with two different elements until it is satisfied it knows which element is larger than which and has sorted them all.

Comment: i still understand it well,. if $x accept array('name' => 'Jon', 'grade' => 98.5) $y accept array('name' => 'Vance', 'grade' => 85.1). then call uasort($students, 'grade_sort'); will be turn uasort($students, 13.4);  how does uasort sort the array.  thank you

Comment: `uasort` is responsible for the sorting. To do that, `uasort` takes two arguments: the array you want to sort, and a function that can compare two elements. `uasort` then takes two random element from that array, and passes them to the function that you provided. That function returns which element was greater/smaller. `uasort` takes that information and sorts the two elements. It repeats these steps until all elements are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`$x` and `$y` are the individual arrays inside your main `$students` arrays. Since you want to sort by their grade, you need to access the `grade` key. Removing it would tell it to compare the arrays instead, which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function you passed to `uasort` will be fed array element on every comparison, thus `return $x < $y` won't make that much sense and meaningless anyway since you are comparing the array instead of the *actual value* inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to correct your code piece.

```
$students = array (
 256 => array ('name' => 'Jon', 'grade' => 98.5),
 2 => array ('name' => 'Vance', 'grade' => 85.1),
 9 => array ('name' => 'Stephen', 'grade' => 94.0),
 364 => array ('name' => 'Steve', 'grade' => 85.1),
 68 => array ('name' => 'Rob', 'grade' => 74.6)
 );  

 function grade_sort($x,$y){
    return ($x['grade'] < $y['grade']);
 }
 uasort ($students,'grade_sort');
 print_r($students);
```

Now coming back to your answer. You can not use `return $x < $y` because $x and $y is an array and you want to compare students grade in your defined function "grade_sort". you can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php for better understanding.